# GTK+ - Typical containers used for several Text Entry and Combo Box widgets?

Tags: user-interface, mono, gtk, gtk#

I'm doing some *for fun* programming so I decided to make my first desktop app with MonoDevelop GTK#. I'm trying to figure out common practices used for creating the GUI.

I have an HPaned where on one side I want to have about 10 - 15 Text Entry and Combo Box widgets. What is the usual container to layout this type of setup? The first thing that comes to mind for me is either use the Table or Fixed container but I don't like the idea of getting far along and figuring out I did something stupid.

Thanks!
Jason

Comment: Do you want them vertically?  With labels or just controls by themselves?  Whatever you do, *don't* use Fixed unless you know why you shouldn't use it in 99.9% of cases and are absolutely certain your case belongs in the other 0.1%.

Comment: I ended up using a combination of vbox and hbox. Thanks for the advice against Fixed!